# EC2 allowing users to sftp

Tags: amazon-ec2, sftp

I have migrated to Amazon EC2. Installed a LAMP and created 2 users for 2 different domain. I have deployed a centos 7 ami.

The problem is i can only login as centos user usig FileZilla. I have created user a and user b also. Isn't it possible to provide them password or create key for them? They can not edit their files.

Comment: you need to use ssh-keygen (or a similar tool) to make a key pair for the users and set the key files up with the correct permissions and mentions in configuration.  See this answer on server fault for some clues http://serverfault.com/questions/241588/how-to-automate-ssh-login-with-password/241593#241593

Comment: i have created using ssh-keygen for the user i have created. but still can not login. actually couldn't understand what to do next. My user is let's say david.

Comment: I think i couldn't explain myself. I need to a user to be able to connect to that server from his windows laptop.

Comment: if you google "how to add ssh key to filezilla" there is a whole page of results

Comment: I know how to add ssh key to Filezilla. I can connect via sftp and ssh but only for ec2-user or centos user (depends on ami). I have created 2 more users in that server.

Comment: The users need to have an .ssh/authorized_keys entry that matches the public key for the private key that is in filezilla.  The first comment I made above has a link to a server fault answer that explains this

Comment: i have read that link. maybe i am very stupid to understand but i can connect and i have sent this private key to user david but he can not connect. That's my problem now.